# How to send SMS with much string from different edittext

Tags: java, android, sms

Here is my code

```js
final EditText editName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        final EditText password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass_login);
        final EditText nohp = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.handphone);
        final EditText repass =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.retype);
        Button submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String pswrd = password.getText().toString();
                    int panjangpass=pswrd.length();
                    String nm = editName.getText().toString();
                    int panjangnm=nm.trim().length();
                    String handphone= nohp.getText().toString();
                    int panjanghp=handphone.trim().length();
                    String rtype = repass.getText().toString();
                    int type=rtype.trim().length();
                    //String pesan=


                    //validasi nama
                    if(panjangnm==0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Insert your name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else if (panjangnm<3){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Name must be more than 3 character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //validasi no hp harus 11-12 angka
                    }else if (panjanghp==0){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Insert your handphone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else if (panjanghp<10 || panjanghp>12) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Your handphone number must between 10-12 number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //validasi password min 6
                    }else if (panjangpass==0){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Insert your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else if (panjangpass<6){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Password minimal 6 character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //validasi retype password, harus sama
                    }else if (type==0){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Type your password again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else if (!rtype.equals(pswrd)){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Password not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //else terakhir untuk kondisi jika sudah terpenuhi semua
                    }else{
                        //disini sebelum balik ke menu awal, kayaknya harus kirim ke database dulu
                        //getText semua inputan data, kirim
                        sendSMS("88170551",nm);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Thank you, " + editName.getText().toString() + " for register to Human Tracker Application.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent back = new Intent(v.getContext(), Mainmenu.class);
                        startActivity(back);
                    }

                }
            });






    }

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message){
    SmsManager sms= SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber,null,message,null,null);
```

i was successfully try sent sms, with this code. But i only try to sent string nm in SMS message , how to send 3 string(pswrd, nm, handphone) to SMS message? so i will receive sms from sender their password, name, and phone number

Comment: put all string to one string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

```
nm = nm + "\n" + handphone + "\n" + pswrd;
```

before

```
sendSMS("88170551",nm);
```

so it look like

```
nm = nm + "\n" + handphone + "\n" + pswrd;
sendSMS("88170551",nm);
```